# Show that the grammar. S->aS|aSbS|Ɛ is ambiguous and find the unambiguous grammar

Tags: context-free-grammar, computation-theory, ambiguous-grammar

I have this question:

Show that the grammar. S->aS|aSbS|Ɛ is ambiguous and find the unambiguous grammar.

I tried learning from the internet whatever I could about ambiguous grammars but most of those try on the same old examples and I feel that they don't convey the approach properly about converting an ambiguous grammar to an unambiguous one. I know there is no one definite method to go about it. I tried a hit an trial approach of sorts and here's what I got:

First of all proof that the given Grammar is ambiguous : try getting aab from the above grammar

You will find that there are at least two ways to go about it.

So I thought about it and came up with a solution using hit and trial.

S -> aT|epsilon
T -> aTbT | epsilon

I have no proof of correctness or too much of a solid thought behind why I came up with this but I at least could not make two different parse trees for aab using this new grammar.

Is this answer correct. I would appreciate it a lot if someone tells me how this is actually done and the rationale behind it instead of doing a hit and trial attempt like me.

Comment: I think a trial and error method is fine for this exercise. It's a search problem. Either you write a parser to search for you, or you search yourself. It's only a short sentence so it's not a lot of work. The proof consists of two valid derivation sequences which are different yet yield the same sentence. I won't do it for you; this is what practise is for!

Comment: Ok, can there be multiple answers(unambiguous grammars) to this question?

Comment: I think i have found another answer to this question and there they have defined a different unambiguous grammar

Comment: Really SO is not for homework stuff. I like grammars so I answered, but perhaps it's best that you remove this question and use SO for real coding issues. Typically people ask questions that have source code as an answer. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

S → U | T 
U → aS | aTbU 
T → aTbT | Ɛ

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

```
S -> aT | eps
T -> aSbS | eps
```

Use induction. The only way for a rule to introduce ambiguities is if itself is ambiguous or if any of the rules it depends on are ambiguous. S does not  introduce ambiguity so T does not introduce ambiguity since it only depends on S and is itself not ambiguous.